# Create 4d numpy array from lists, where axis[i] holds the list[i] elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have three lists, and I can build a numpy array of objects with `(3,2,4)` shape from them.

However, what I want is a numpy array with shape `(2, 3, 4)`, where each axis corresponds to a "variable" in the list.
I tried using `np.reshape` with no success.

```
import numpy as np
p1 = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
p2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
p3 = [[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
points = [p1, p2, p3]
nparr = np.array(points, dtype=np.float32)
```

What I obtain is

```
[[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[2. 2. 2. 2.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2.]]]
```

But what I would like to obtain is

```
[[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2.]]  

[[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [2. 2. 2. 2.]]
```

Is there a clean way to achieve this without having to change the original input lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nparr = np.array([a for a in zip(p1,p2,p3)], dtype=np.float32)
```

or

```
nparr = np.squeeze(np.array([list(zip(p1,p2,p3))]), dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: I chose this as the answer because if was fitting my needs better at the time, but both are very valuable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a **transposition** of the two first axis using:

```py
nparr.transpose(1, 0, 2)
```

Since `transpose` return a view of the array with modified strides, this operation is very very cheap. However, on big array, it may be better to copy the view using `.copy()` so to work on *contiguous views*.